# DataTable instance get HTML element ID

Tags: jquery, datatables

## Context:

I am playing with multiple DataTables at the same time (same page). I keep as global variables the DataTables object, e.g.

```
window.table_one = $('#mytableOne').DataTable( options );
[...]
window.table_two = $('#theirTableTwo').DataTable( options2 );
```

## Problem:

As much as I could find on https://datatables.net and stackoverflow, the DataTables does not allow to get to the id of the HTML element table upon which DataTables is invoked.

## Attempt:

Fortunately, we can use jQuery from the DataTables object, hence grab the id:

```
window.table_one.$('tr').closest('table').attr('id')
```

But calling jQuery like this feels like mashing strawberries with a tank, do you have lighter way to do so?

My other thought is to keep the DataTables instance in a global 'array', along with the html id. e.g.

```
window.tables = {
    'mytableOne': $('#mytableOne').DataTable( options )
}
[...]
window.tables[ '#theirTableTwo' ].DataTable( options2 )
```

Which looks lighter but uglier.

What are the good practices? I know that global vars should be feared, but I am kind of stuck with it (maintain old website).

Comment: DataTables will return the existing api instance after the table has been setup just call $('#mytableOne').DataTable() with no options.  It is my assumption this is what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: Hi Paul, since I cannot guess the selector of the DataTable (in fact, I am looking for it), your proposition is the inverse of what I am looking for. Nevertheless, nice try :) davidkonrad gave a good solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [**`$.fn.dataTable.tables()`**](https://datatables.net/reference/api/%24.fn.dataTable.tables()). This return a vanilla `NodeList` of all table elements that has been initialised as a DataTable. For example, in your case

```js
console.log( $.fn.dataTable.tables()[0].id );
```

would return `mytableOne`. So iterate over that NodeList and you can get all `id`'s (or DOM nodes). A perfect replacement for your global array. That could also be useful for example if your table `id` is dynamically created with a timestamp or unique random number you not know upfront.

You can work with the API on an unknown table `id` like this :

```
var temp = $('#'+$.fn.dataTable.tables()[0].id).DataTable();
temp.row.add(['a','b','c']).draw();
```

Answer (score 4):

If you already have the dataTable instance you can try this:

```
myDataTable.context[0].sTableId
```

Comment: Indeed! and also `datatable_composants.context[0].nTable.id` and `datatable_composants.context[0].oInstance.attr('id')`